# How can I save the results of different runs in a compare runs experiment in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I want to save the results of different runs in a compare runs experiment in Anylogic in an excel sheet or to some variable or output so that I use these values for some further calculations. How can I do that

Answer (score 1):

Another flexible way of doing this is by writing the results to CSV. This should work for any kind of simulation or experiment with AnyLogic.

You'd have to import standard external libraries into the environment and add code to the experiment to be executed at the end of a simulation run.

Under imports section you could have this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
```

First create a variable for the filename called csvFileName (you can call it whatever obviously). Then create a function in root called updateMyCSV() or something like that. This function would have a general structure of:

```
FileWriter pw = new FileWriter(csvFileName, true);

StringBuilder sb;
sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(<variablename>); sb.append(',');
```

Then repeat the above for each variable you want exported

Then finish the function with:

```
sb.append('\n');
    
pw.append(sb);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best use the build-in database and let it write to Excel at the end of all your runs.

Create a dbase table with columns such as "run_number", "replication_number", "experiment_parameter_X", "my_result_y". Each of your params on Main should get a column (at least those you vary) and each of the output values you are interested in.

This way, you can easily write your model results after each model run using the `insertInto` command ([link](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fconnectivity%2Fquerying.html&resultof=%22%69%6E%73%65%72%74%69%6E%74%6F%22%20)).

Finally, just tick the "write to Excel" tickbox in your dbase, select the file and it will write all your raw results.

Also check the example models using the dbase, several use this approach